# Sql Server connection string in client machine

Tags: c#, sql-server

i am new for sql server and i am planing for create pos system using c# and sql server.i know how to create connection string in my macihine
after creating pos system how can i implement in my client machine?
what is the requrement in client machine.
how to connect sql database with my project in client machine
client use normal pc and not server
thank you

Comment: the requirements are the same for your machine and the client. A connection string

Comment: You should be using the windows credentials which are secure.  Two PC cannot connect without the PC being in the same windows group.  So I normally make a windows group account and put the user(s) into the same group on both client and server PC.  The have the database use the windows group account for credentials.  The use a connections string with : Trusted_Connection=True;.  See : https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you host the application and the database server on the same machine? In this case you can just connect to the localhost instance of the SQL Server.

There are a lot of examples which can be found on [Connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/).

Most common will be `Server=localhost;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;` or for integrated security (preferred in this situation) `Server=localhost;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;`.

If you do this, you might also want to check out the possibility to encrypt/secure your 'secrets' of the configuration file.
Some details on the matter can be found on these sites for example:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203213/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/021506-1.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dx0f3cf2(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Your connection string may look like this:

```
 data source=localhost;initial catalog=pos;uid=sa;pwd=password
```

After that ,create a connection in SQL server in the client machine. Make sure you have the same databasename with same SQL server credentials in the client machine.